# x86 assembly recursive function -> Illegal instruction error

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

Code1: implements main function which calls fact (factorial) function

```
section .data
    msg db "Enter the Number whose factorial is to be calculated",10,0
    msg1 db "The factorial is: ",0
    ioput db "%d"

section .bss
    a resd 1

section .text
    global main
    extern printf,scanf,fact
main:   
    pusha 
    push msg
    call printf
    add esp,4
    popa

    pusha 
    push a
    push ioput
    call scanf
    add esp,8
    popa

    mov ebx,dword[a]

    pusha
    push ebx
    call fact
    add esp,4


    pusha
    push msg1
    call printf
    add esp,4
    popa

    pusha
    push eax
    push ioput
    call printf
    add esp,8
    popa

    ret
```

Code2 which implements fact (factorial function):

```
section .text
    global fact
    extern printf,scanf
fact:   
    enter 0,0
    cmp ebx,1
    jnz next
    ret

next:
    push ebx
    dec ebx
    call fact
    pop ebx
    mul eax,ebx
    leave
    ret
```

System stats: 32 bit machine, Ubuntu 14.04, Nasm is used

Problem statement: Program received signal `SIGILL`, Illegal instruction. Why am I getting this error?

Comment: The `pusha`'s and `popa`'s are not even balanced. Check the block containing `call fact`. Return will go somewhere interesting this way.

Comment: Also, learn to use a debugger.

Answer (score 2):

```
mov ebx,dword[a]

pusha
push ebx
call fact
add esp,4
```

This is the part of your program that has some problems!

1. You need to initialize EAX to get meaningful results from calling *fact*. A convenient number would be 1.
2. Since you used `pusha` you also need to use `popa`. I would have preferred none because your code doesn't really need it.
3. The *fact* routine doesn't use a parameter passed on the stack. It simply uses the EBX register for that purpose. This means that you can omit `push ebx` and `add esp,4` and also that you could remove the `enter` and `leave` instructions from *fact*.

This is the code you could write to solve it all.

```
mov ebx,dword[a]
mov eax,1
pusha
call fact
mov [esp+28],eax
popa
```

A shorter version is

```
mov ebx,dword[a]
mov eax,1
call fact
```

Comment: thanks ! but i do not understand as to why have you done :                                   mov [esp+28],eax

Comment: Without this instruction the `popa` would have replaced the result of *fact* in EAX with the value of EAX saved by `pusha`. The offset +28 is the exact spot where `pusha` has stored EAX.